# Schrödinger’s input

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Why might an input in an AngularJS form be $touched when logging the whole form, but then logging the individual input immediately after return $untouched?

`console.log(form, form.fieldName.$touched)`

In the `form` object I see that the field in question has a state of `$touched`, but the result of the second argument logged is false. I am expecting the state to be `$touched`, and believe this to be the way to test this at an individual input level?

Comment: When you look at the form object in your console, you are seeing the state of the form object *when you actually look at it*, not how it was when it was at the console.log statement.  There is probably something that is re-setting the form and/or clearing the `$touched` state for that field after you log it out.